# Convergence of improper integral

Tags: calculus

For which values of $p$ does the follwing converge:

1. $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{e^{-px}}{\ln x} dx $
2. $\int_2^{\infty} x^{p-1}e^{-x} dx $

THIS IS NOT A HW QUESTION, so please- if someone can explain to me the process of solving this at infinity using the limit version of  the comparison test , it will be great!

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For $p>0$ we have
  $$\frac{e^{-px}}{\ln x}=_\infty o\left(\frac 1 {x^2}\right)$$
  so the given integral is convergent.
- For $p=0$ we have
  $$\frac{1}{\ln x}\ge \frac{1}{ x}\quad \text{for $x$ large enough}$$
  so the integral is divergent.
- For $p<0$
  $$\frac{e^{-px}}{\ln x}\to \infty$$
  so also the integral is divergent.

  Now for the second integral we have 
  $$x^{p-2}e^{-x}=_\infty o\left(\frac 1 {x^2}\right)\quad \forall p$$
  so the integral is convergent.